# Организация БД в соц.сети

Tags: mysql

Соц.сеть в которой есть подписки.
В общем есть 4 таблицы

**1) users**

id | nmae | surname |settings | likes | posts | commetns | subscribes | avatar | photos

**2) information**

id | interest | activities | familystatus | floor ...

**3) Posts and Comments**

idposts | iduser | text

**4) Photo**

idphoto | path | comments | likes | iduser

Многие поля хранятся в сsv. Такая структура нормальная ?

Comment: Нет, это вряд ли будет приемлимо при большой нагрузке. Нужны НФ.

Comment: Почему сразу аббревиатуру НФ на расшифровать, а не ждать, пока попросят?

Comment: @michael, если я не ошибаюсь то НФ - это нормальная форма.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чем обусловлено хранение в CSV? Если впоследствии Вы собираетесь такие поля парсить, то это может существенно увеличить накладные расходы и снизить общую скорость работы программы. Может стоит разнести эти данные в разные поля? Выделить больше сущностей или использовать таблицы связей? Словом вариантов много, но в CSV хранить данные, которые будут часто использоваться и обновляться я не рекомендую